# Looping try...catch... to make sure input is valid or use control statements?

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch

I have question about try...catch... usage. 
I wanted to know how to make good use of try....catch... in situations like when a user inputs a wrong data and it needs to be corrected before program proceeds. In first code I cannot use continue without a loop and if I wanted to use loop I could simply use if...else... for error checking like second code. Would I really need try...catch... ?

```
int size;
try
{
    cin >> size;
    Stack stack(size); //create a Stack(int) object.
}
catch(InvalidStackSize e)
{
    cerr << "Invalid size for stack.\n";
    continue; //What should I do here to ensure a stack with right size is entered before proceeding with rest of the program?
}
```

In second code I use a loop statement with if...else... . If I always need to have loops to get the right user input, why use try...catch... ?

```
int size;
Stack stack;
do
{
    cin >> size;
    if( size == 0 )
        continue;
    else
    {
        Stack tmp(size);
        stack = tmp;
        break;
    }
}while(true);
```

Comment: You should only be using exceptions for _exceptional behavior_. A simple if conditional would work here. So your answer is no.

Comment: You should probably create a function `int get_integer_until_non_zero()` to get rid of the while loop in your main code: `Stack stack{get_integer_until_non_zero()};`.

Comment: Exceptions should be limited to handling exceptional situations. Users making mistakes in their input is not exceptional.

Comment: _"Why use try catch?"_  Very few C++ features are mandatory when solving any particular problem.  Are you asking for opinions on this topic?

Comment: @DrewDormann Wanted to make sure I'm not missing any _try catch_ features...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exceptions` are meant for *exceptional behaviour*  not for *error checking(compile time error)*. `Exceptions` happens in the middle of execution of an instruction and once *exception* occurs and if you are not handling those *exception* properly then next instruction will not be executed & process stops.

From the `C++ Standard`

> Exception handling provides a way of transferring control and
>   information from a point in the execution of a thread to an exception
>   handler associated with a point previously passed by the execution.

So to handle those exceptions, `C++` suggested exception handling using `try`, `throw` and `catch`.

For below code `exception handling` is not required, because any instruction of the code will not cause any `exception` or `runtime error`, to handle compile time error you can use `if..else` as you did.

```
do
{
    cin >> size;
    if( size == 0 )
        continue;
    else
    {
        Stack tmp(size);
        stack = tmp;
        break;
    }
}while(true);
```

Comment: If I create a stack with size = 0, I still won't get compile error though... should I use this code in constructor to ensure right input is entered or just set stack size = 1 if 0 was entered?

Comment: If user entered size as `zero` or `negative value` you should handle using normal `if/else` statement. In constructor if received `size` is `zero`, don't create the `stack`.